# How to Set SSL Verify Peer False on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, ssl

My web-service using Code-Ignite something like this "'ssl_verify_peer' => FALSE"

How do I set the same thing on Android? This is my Code when I contact to server:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+holder);
httpGet.setHeader("X-API-KEY","043c7dd954b0631be2541bc65645917c52d63b0c");
httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
```

Comment: The solution provided here can be used in Android : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4837230/2083078

Comment: **Don't do that**! It defeats all of the security of SSL.